# 2006 MySQL server has gone away while saving object

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

Im getting this error "General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away" when saving an object.

Im not going to paste the code since it way too complicated and I can explain with this example, but first a bit of context:

Im executing a function via Command line using Phalcon tasks, this task creates a Object from a Model class and that object calls a casperjs script that performs some actions in web page, when it finishes it saves some data, here's where **sometimes** I get mysql server has gone away, only when the casperjs takes a bit longer.
Task.php

```
 function doSomeAction(){
      $object = Class::findFirstByName("test");
      $object->performActionOnWebPage();
 }
```

In Class.php

```
function performActionOnWebPage(){
    $result = exec ("timeout 30s casperjs somescript.js");
    if($result){
        $anotherObject = new AnotherClass();
        $anotherObject->value = $result->value;
        $anotherObject->save();
    }
 }
```

It seems like the **$anotherObject->save();** method is affected by the time **exec ("timeout 30s casperjs somescript.js");** takes to get an answer, when it shouldn`t.
Its not a matter of the data saved since it fails and saves succesfully with the same input, the only difference I see is the time casperjs takes to return a value.
It seems like if for some reason phalcon opens the MySQL conection during the whole execution of the "Class.php" function, provoking the timeout when casperjs takes too long, does this make any sense? Could you help me to fix it or find a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems that either you are trying to fetch heavy data in single packet than allowed in your mysql config file or your wait_timeout variable value is not set properly as per your code requirement.

check your `wait_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet` values, you can check by below command-

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

And increase these values as per your requirement in your `my.cnf (linux) or my.ini (windows)` config file and restart mysql service.

Comment: Yes, that was my first guess, but when the casperjs is fast its saves everything without problem, being the same data. Also is very simple data.

Comment: Issue seems wait_timeout as earlier casperjs wll be taking more time than this variable and now you have optimized casperjs code so it is executing quickly and you are not getting issue....Definitely first we have to optimize our code instead of changing DB variables blindly.